# QGIS older version to download onto a Mac ios 10.7.5

Tags: qgis, mac

I am unable to download the newest QGIS to my macbook pro (2011, ios 10.7.5) because I need ios 10.8. Unfortunately, I am also unable to update my computer at this time. On th QGIS website there is an option to download older versions, however I don't know which version to use.

Can anyone help/tell me what version I should download?

Answer (score 1):

From the main download page, there is a current build out there for 10.7.

> Mac Installer Package for both OS X Mavericks (10.9), Mountain Lion (10.8) and Lion (10.7).  http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Comment: The QGIS download page says that the download works for 10.7, but the Kyng Chaos page specifies only 10.8 upward.  Is there a version of QGIS available that can be installed for OS X 10.7.5?